# Chat application in Java over the Internet | ConnectException (connection timed out)

Tags: java, timeout, port, forwarding, connectexception

I'm trying to develop a basic chat application. I've written the required codes for both the server and the client, and the application works perfectly fine over the LAN. When I tried to make it work over the Internet, however, I got stuck. I learned that I need to make a port-forwarding in the server machine, and I did that. I forwarded the port 6000 and canyouseeme.org gave a successful message. So, the port is surely open and no firewall is blocking it. However, the client code cannot connect to it.

The server code opens a ServerSocket as follows (their definitions are made previously):

```
InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6000, 10, IP);
connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
```

And the client code tries to connect to it mainly using the following code:

```
clientSocket = new Socket("xx.xxx.xxx.xx", 6000);
```

where xx.xxx.xxx.xx is the server machine's IP address (not the local one with 192.168.x.x).

Is this a Java issue? I am asking because the port 6000 is apparently open and canyouseeme.org can successfully connect to it, but my client fails to do so. Why such a thing happens? Any help would be appreciated (For further info, please read the comments below).

The error message is below:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:180)
    at ChatPanel$ConnectButtonListener.actionPerformed(ChatPanel.java:206)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Comment: Make sure no firewalls blocking the call and port is open.

Comment: Well, as I have said, the port is already open and no firewall is blocking it. Could a firewall block the outgoing request of the client? If that is so, how can I check it?

Comment: make sure you're forwarding the port to the correct internal address (from the router).  Local addresses will change without warning if you've not set them up to be static.

Comment: Yes I already did make it to be static. It is 192.168.2.15 and the router forwards the port to exactly the same local address.

Comment: Can you telnet from the client to the remote port? `telnet hostname 6000` from the command line.

Comment: does the server process bind to the correct ip address?  depending on the server configuration, `getLocalHost()` could return a variety of different things.

Comment: @matt b --> I tried it now. I can telnet over the LAN, but not from a different network as I want to.

Comment: @jtahlborn --> I am printing the value of getLocalHost() as well, just to check, and it prints 192.168.2.15 as expected. So, I don't think it causes the problem.

Comment: Use `InternetAddress.getByName` or don't use this parameter at all.

Comment: @RomanC Consider it as `welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);`, as it was my original code. It was just a dummy change of code, but I got the message.

Comment: How did you check that port forwarding works?

Comment: @RomanC Well, I've added adn additional rule in my router settings to forward any incoming request from port 6000 to the local IP address 192.168.2.15. Then I added an exception in the Windows Defender for port 6000 and disabled my normal firewall. I checked via canyouseeme.org, and it says "Your ISP is not blocking the port 6000". The port should be open, considering this message. However, does it forward to the local IP address successfully, that I don't know. Is there a way to check that?

Comment: @mattb I managed to telnet the server from the port 23. And I changed my little chat program to make its connection over the port 23. Still no luck :/ So I guess it is not a port-forwarding or firewall issue. The client can connect to the server over the net, but not with this Java code. What is it that I am doing wrong to establish a connection over the Internet with Java?

Comment: Did you check that your server is listening on the specified port? How did you do that?

Comment: @RomanC When the server part of the program is not open on the server computer, canyouseeme.org gives an error message, since the port is not being listened. When I open it, however, the same website can access to that port, displaying a success messsage. So, I think the server is listening on the specified port.

Do I need to make some arrangements on the client part as well? In the end the connection is two-sided,and the server needs to return a specific message to the client following the request for a successful connection.How can I check whether the server returns a message to the client?

Comment: Opening socket streams, but you didn't get connection. Did you try `netstat -bna` or relevant to your OS. Do you use IPv6?

Comment: @RomanC No, I'm using IPv4 addresses in the chat program. On the server part, I tried `netstat -bna` now. It shows the port 23(because I changed it to be 23) is being listened by the java.exe. The local address is 0.0.0.0:23 and the foreign address is 0.0.0.0:0.

Comment: @RomanC Well, I just got connected over the port 23! It is, however, quite interesting that I changed nothing. Then I tried the port 6000 and I could not get a connection. I checked `netstat -bna` on the client computer, and the message was "SYN_SENT".

Comment: My intention was to use a port that would not conflict with any other software. 6000 is just a wild-choice.

Comment: 6000 is a known port, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: Oh, let me try a port that is not listed there and share the result again.

Comment: Nah, it(port 5192) didn't work either. I guess I will continue with the port 23, as it seems the only one working.

@RomanC Thanks for your help! Above all, thanks for your interest in my problem. Now that I have a server working, I can advance to coding multi-thread chatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client you should use

```
clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByAddress(addr), port);
```

where `addr` is the public address of the server and `port` is the server bound to.

Comment: I made this change and now I can connect over the port 23 without any problems. Thank you. But still port 6000 causes some trouble. So, I guess 6000 is not a wise port choice. What dou you think, should I still keep 23 or find myself a dummy port like 5192?

Comment: Did you check that NAT/Firewall configuration. If you have a port forwarding problems try this http://netcallback.sourceforge.net

Comment: I am now using the server computer via TeamViewer and it takes too long to change even a single setting. So, after a couple of hours I will get to home and I will try a bunch of different ports. If I cannot connect via any other port than 23, I will check the link you suggested and I will post it here.

Comment: I just connected over the port 61223. Thank you again :)